# Angular JWT tokens

Tags: angular, authorization, jwt

When I try to call a Get from my ASP.NET Web Api through Postman, I can succesfully authorize myself, but when I do this through Angular with hardcoded the same JWT bearer token I keep getting no authorization.

Can someone help me with what is causing this problem?
[image: Postman]

[image: Console logs]

[image: Angular code]

Comment: 1. Don't post images of the code, post the actual code. 2. What is `authHttp`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be having the

```
Authorization : 'JWT ____________'
```

and not Bearer